# How does the opcode JUMP work in the EVM Stack?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, evm

I'm following along on the "Advanced Solidity" tutorial [here](https://github.com/androlo/solidity-workshop/blob/master/tutorials/2016-03-11-advanced-solidity-II.md).

I ran into an example I'm having trouble understanding.
[image: example image]

In this example, why does JUMP affect the state of the stack? I expected it to only affect the program counter.

(i.e. I would expect after JUMP, at PC: 11, the length of the stack would be 3, not 2. The JUMP comes after PUSH 0x0B.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to refer to the original docs. As stated in the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) :

0x56 JUMP 1 0 Alter the program counter

Where 1 is the number of items taken out of the stack, 0 the number of items returned. So in your case JUMP removes '0b' from the stack and use it as the destination (PC = 11 = 0x0b).

Comment: Thanks Jakub, that's helpful. I keep forgetting to refer back to the yellow paper when confused.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

`JUMP` takes the value at the top of the stack to use as the destination.
That value "becomes" the destination.

A `JUMP` could be thought of as performing a `PUSH` first, and moving the program counter to the pushed value.

Credit to Martin / @holiman on the `ethereum/tests` Gitter. Thanks.